# JavaScript to scroll text across the screen

Tags: javascript

I am slightly new to JavaScript.

I wrote the following code to scroll some text across the screen

```
<html>


    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function move(){
                document.getElementById('id1').style.right=(document.getElementById('id1').style.right-10)+'px';
                setTimeout(move,20);
            }
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <div id='id1' class="divclass" style="right:1100px; position:absolute">
                Here is text!
            </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="button" onclick="move()" value="move">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>    
    </body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't do the job. I don't know where the error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The css style of right is not actually a number, it is a number followed by a unit. Therefore (1100px - 10) + 'px' is actually: 'Nanpx'. This is because you are trying to subtract from a string value. Use the parseInt function to parse the 1100 out of 1100px. Then perform your math. Then add your unit.

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer with the checkmark then! Don't forget to register!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd prefer keeping the 'x' value externally, e.g.:

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var intX = 1100;
function move(){
    var objDiv = document.getElementById('id1');
    if ( objDiv != null ) {
        objDiv.style.left = (intX -= 3).toString() + 'px';
        } //if
    if ( intX > 0 ) { setTimeout(move,20); }
return true;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="id1" class="divclass" style="left:1100px; position:absolute; white-space:nowrap;">Here is text!</div>
<input type="button" onclick="move()" value="move">
</body>
</html>
```